# How to reset an EJS document without restarting the server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I'm using Node.js and EJS as the template engine.

The problem I'm facing is that whenever I output a text using EJS, the text remains in the document even after refreshing the page and closing the tab, the only way for the document to reset to its initial state is when I restart the server.

This has caused me a big problem when I pushed my project into production, because if an output is generated by User 'A', then when User 'B' visits my web app he will see the changes that were made by User 'A' in the document.

Here is an example to show the idea of what I'm actually doing in my main project:

Suppose User 'A' opens my web app from his own device, he typed "Hello" and clicks on the button to print Hello in the browser:

[image]

Now when User 'B' opens my web app from his own device, he will see the same "Hello" printed because of User 'A', which I obviously don't want.

[image]

What User 'B' is supposed to see:

[image]

The same goes for user 'C', 'D', 'E' and all the visitors of my web app.

I know EJS is supposed to help me generate dynamic data, but what's the point of that if that dynamic data is going to appear to all visitors that haven't asked for it?

If one user makes a change, then that change will appear to all my visitors.

My EJS code:

```
<body>

    <form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="text">
        <button>Click to see text</button>
    </form>
    
    <h1><%= text %> </h1>
    
</body>
```

My Node.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Listening on 3000"))
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

let text = ''

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render('index', {text});
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
   res.redirect('/')
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear code snippets. Each user needs to effectively have their own `text` variable. If they all share one variable, this is what happens. There are a lot of ways to achieve separation, from an in-memory object to a database to a file to local storage. Sessions might be useful. EJS isn't really part of the situation. How you solve the issue depends on what you're trying to achieve ultimately. What sort of app are you trying to make?

Comment: Adding to ggorlen's comment, [express-session](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html) is one (of multiple) ways of storing data (for some time) _per user_. The linked page may be a little hard to understand if you don't know what a session is, but the code samples will help.